# Eggs used as Binders

Tags: eggs, food-science, ingredient-selection

Eggs are commonly used as a binder in meatballs and other foods.

If separated, is one part of the egg a stronger binder:

- Is the white a stronger binder than the yolk?
- Is the yolk stronger than the white?
- Is either separated portion a stronger binder than the whole egg?

Comment: I'm sure there's a difference, I'm trying to find the science before adding an answer

Comment: Depending on the answers you get, I might be interested in a follow-up question about the resulting texture (I sometimes make savoury oat/cheese/egg flapjacks and they can turn out a little rubbery with too much egg, but much less and they fall apart) +1

Answer (score 3):

Further research using Google has provided the information I was seeking though not in the form I had posed my question. It might be helpful if I first state what I'm ultimately trying to achieve:

- I want to make chicken nuggets using only chicken thigh meat (and possibly chicken skin).

On my previous attempt, I used whole egg as a binder and achieved less than satisfactory results: [over here](https://oureverydaylife.com/use-egg-white-binding-burgers-39662.html) I found a recipe mentioning that using the egg white, which has much more protein than the yolk (mostly fat), would give me the best shot at succeeding:

[Lean Poultry Patties:](https://oureverydaylife.com/use-egg-white-binding-burgers-39662.html)

- Unlike beef, ground turkey and chicken, either alone or in combination, benefit from the addition of egg whites when forming burger patties.
- The egg whites help the lean meat to bind together, especially if you're using additional ingredients such as chopped vegetables.
- To form patties made with ground poultry, use a food processor to chop vegetables such as onion, pepper or mushrooms into small pieces.
- Use one egg white per 1 pound of meat.
- A tablespoon of savory flavoring to the meat mixture, such as soy sauce or barbecue sauce, adds body and moisture